# Index of Coincidence Averages List

Tags: classical-cipher, index-of-coincidence

I am looking for a comprehensive list of the IOC values of any or all classical ciphers. I can't find a list, only pieces. Each cipher has an average IOC value, and I was wondering if there was a comprehensive list of these values for every classical cipher available. Can anyone share a list of these IOC values?

Comment: the IOC is obtained from a ciphertext corresponding to some given concrete plaintext. Under a statistical model for the natural language (English, say) the plaintext belongs to, it should be close to the collision probability $\sum_{x\in \{A,B,\ldots,Z\}} p_x^2$ of the natural language. So, what are you exactly asking?

Comment: @kodlu Added a bit more, take a look please.

Answer (score 1):

The index of coincidence (IOC) measures the likelihood of drawing two matching characters by randomly selecting two characters from a given ciphertext.  It also applies to digraphs, etc.

So, the chance of drawing a given character or grouping from a given ciphertext is: (number of times that character or grouping appears / length of the text).

The index of coincidence applies to ciphertexts, not to ciphers.  Friedman's IOC does not apply to a cipher itself--not to the Alberti cipher, the Vigenère cipher, etc.

---

See:  William F. Friedman, The Index of Coincidence and Its Applications in Cryptanalysis, Aegean Park Press, 1996.

A [declassified NSA document](https://www.nsa.gov/Portals/70/documents/news-features/declassified-documents/friedman-documents/correspondence/FOLDER_152/41746979078617.pdf) about the IOC that links to that august institution.